# Rename files uploaded in Django admin and omit fields in the form

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 3.0.5 and I want to upload images in the Django admin.

I'm trying to:

1) change the filename uploaded the media folder based on the image data.

2) Omit fields in the displayed form because these are auto generated.

The model is registered in admin.py

This is my code in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from hashlib import md5
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

class NewImage(models.Model):

    image_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    extension = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, default='')
    image_hash = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True, db_column='hash', default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image_name

    @staticmethod
    def hash_exists(hash):
        return NewImage.objects.filter(image_hash=hash).exists()

    def generate_name(self):
        try:
            img_id = NewImage.objects.values('id').order_by('-id').first()['id'] + 1
        except:
            img_id = 1
        self.image_name = "%s_%s" % (img_id, self.image_hash[-4:])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        img = Image.open(self.image)
        self.image_hash = md5(img.tobytes()).hexdigest()

        if not self.pk:
            try:
                if self.hash_exists(self.image_hash):
                    raise ValueError("image hash already exists, duplicate image!")
            except ValueError as err:
                print(err.args)
                return ""

        self.width, self.height = img.size
        self.extension = img.format.lower()
        self.generate_name()

        super(NewImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

1) How can I have the file in the media folder be `image_name`

2) For omitting the fields. Based on SOF answers, I tried the following (it doesn't work) in forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import NewImage

class NewImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = NewImage
        exclude = ['image_name','height','width','extension','image_hash']

class NewImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['image_name','height','width','extension','image_hash']
    form = NewImageForm
```

Comment: Didn't `upload_to='images/'` work for you?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I uploads it in that folder but doesn't change the filename to the name returned by generate_name()